# Executing JavaScript script in Flutter/Dart

Tags: javascript, android, flutter, dart

I'm having a little trouble figuring out how to execute JS code in Flutter. So here's the detailed information:

1. I'm trying to make an online-radio Android/IOS application. What it basically does is just stream the music and show name and the artist of the track.
2. I already connected to the radio stream and it works fine.
3. They send the name and the artist of the track by this link:
   https://embed.radio.co/embed/scc370f2b2/song.js
4. I can't figure out the way to extract this data in flutter. I'm thinking just running separate server that takes the name of the track encodes it in JSON and sends to flutter app, but I'm not sure if it's the right way to do it. Can somebody help me out?

Comment: are you sure they don't have an API which gives you this data as JSON?

Comment: @LoVe I'm not sure they gave any. This is how they told us they get it